# If link has class, apply style + append text

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out how to add a style to a link & append text if it has a certain class.

e.g.

```
$("a").hasClass("Woohoo"));
$(".Woohoo").css({ font-style: "italic" });
$('.Woohoo').append('Some text');
} 

<a href=#">link 1</a>
<a class="Woohoo" href=#">link 2</a>
<a href=#">link 2</a>
```

should output:

*link 2 Some text*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for Hyphenated properties and use [Element Selector (“element”)](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) along with [Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to target the desired element.

```
$("a.Woohoo").css({ fontStyle: "italic" }).append('Some text');
```

OR

```
$("a.Woohoo").css({ "font-style": "italic" }).append('Some text');
```

```js
$("a.Woohoo").css({
  fontStyle: "italic"
}).append('Some text');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href=#">link 1</a>
<a class="Woohoo" href=#">link 2</a>
<a href=# ">link 2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply select link with class and do the remaining things. The property should be either quoted since it contains `-` in it or use came cased `fontStyle` instead.

```js
$("a.Woohoo").css({
  'font-style': "italic"
}).append('Some text');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href=# ">link 1</a>
<a class="Woohoo " href=#">link 2</a>
<a href=# ">link 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could loop through all the link elements with that class

```
$("a").each(function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass("Woohoo") ) {
        // do some magic here
    }
});
```

Or nicer

```
$("a.Woohoo").each(function () {
    // do some magic here
});
```

But simply

```
$("a.Woohoo").css(... //etc
```

Should do what you want